# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] - how to make if to compare with base url

Tags: php, http-referer

I'm trying to compare value of HTTP_REFERER and my base url . How to do that? If I write it in this way, it doesn't show back button. If I use whole url of my project: 
http://localhost/myproject/index.php/home/index
It works, but I want to compare base url - not to write many if conditions for each page. How could I do that?

```html
<?php 
if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) )) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ==  'http://localhost:/myproject/') {
        echo '<a type="button" onclick="history.back(-1);">Back</a>';
    }
}
```

Edited: In this way it'working but it's showing this warning:
Message: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
How to fix it?

```html
<?php
if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) )) { $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; $current = 'localhost:/myproject/';
$ref =parse_url($referer); $my=parse_url($current);
if (strtolower($ref) === strtolower($my)) { echo '<a type="button" onclick="history.back(-1);">Back</a>'; } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if in HTTP_REFERER its constains your domain.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'localhost/myproject' !== false))
{
  echo '<a type="button" onclick="history.back(-1);">Back</a>';
}
```

Comment: It works without this: " !== false". Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) )) {
    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $current = 'http://localhost:/myproject/'; // Do you mean for the : to be here?

    $refererBaseUrl = trim(preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $referer), '/');
    $currentBaseUrl = trim(preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $current), '/');

    if (strtolower($refererBaseUrl) === strtolower($currentBaseUrl)) {
        echo '<a type="button" onclick="history.back(-1);">Back</a>';
    }
}
```

This is the basic technique that I use to compare base URLs.

**Edit**:

How about using `parse_url` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to parse both URLs and compare results?

Comment: It doesn't show me Back button. You mean :  if (strtolower($refererBaseUrl) === strtolower($currentBaseUrl)) {
                        echo '<a type="button" onclick="history.back(-1);">Back</a>';
                    }

Comment: I tried this and it's working:Thanks. if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) )) {
                    $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
                    $current = 'http://localhost:/myproject/';

                     $ref =parse_url($referer);
                     $my=parse_url($current);
                    if (strtolower($ref) === strtolower($my)) {
                        echo '<a type="button" onclick="history.back(-1);">Back</a>';
                    }
                }

Comment: It's showing this warning: Message: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Answer (score 0):

You can get the base URL using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` you may need to append `http/https` to the string.

You can also then use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the remainder of the URL.